# How can I extract triples from the Freebase dump?

Tags: rdf, freebase, triples, knowledge-graph, n-triples

I would like to collect a large knowledge base of triples as: **subject**, **object**, **predicate**, so I downloaded the Freebase dump from the [developers page](https://developers.google.com/freebase/#freebase-rdf-dumps), which contains triples in RDF format, and I want to decode it to a readable format. How can I achieve this?

Currently I am following the Github of [nchah](https://github.com/nchah/freebase-triples)

and am running the shell script ***s0-run-parse-extract-triples.sh*** on VirtualBox Ubuntu, which should clean the input data of RDF's by removing URL's but keeping the ID's, and am passing my input data as ***freebase-triples.txt*** which is a sample of 100 rows from the 30Gb  ***freebase-rdf-latest.gz*** as argument.

you can find the code [here](https://github.com/nchah/freebase-triples/blob/master/scripts/shell/s0-run-parse-extract-triples.sh)

Note that I was getting the message **No such file in directory**, so I removed line 8, and added **$1** in line 17 instead of **$INPUT_FILE** which took care of this message, and also in line 21 I removed the **#** sign and changed **gsed** to **sed**, and I also added echo messages to do some tracing.

and this is how am running it:`sh s0-run-parse-extract-triples.sh freebase-triples.txt`

Check the error that am getting [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9R28.png)

Am getting the output file **fb-rdf-s01-c01** but it still has the URL's and its unchanged from my input, and am also getting the other file **fb-rdf-s01-c02** but its empty .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include your error message here, as text, rather than linking to an image on an external site. The source data is in N Triples format, ie a TSV with <subject> <predicate> <object> ".". To convert to Subject Object Predicate format, just throw away column 4 and move column 3 before column 2.

Comment: @TomMorris Thank you for replying, my issue is that I am getting the ID's, but I want the values. I am using zgrep to pull some rows, how can I get the value of m.012m11bj in <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.012m11bj> ?

Comment: That *is* the value. It's an object identifier. If you want some attribute of the object, say its name, you'll need to find the triples that has m.012m11bj as the subject and "rdfs:label" as the predicate. Those triples will have a set of strings in various languages as the objects.

Comment: @TomMorris thanks for the insightful information, my output is a list of triples, how can I get the names for the whole list? here is my question in a clear manner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71493269/how-to-get-the-subject-and-object-values-from-freebase-given-the-relation